# Windows don't stay where you put them?

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, windows, snap-store

I would like to know why the windows of the snapstore applications are blocked and always appear in the same place at the top left

[image: Screenshot]

And it doesn't matter where I put the window on the screen! I mean by saying this, that when I open applications from the snapstore the window always comes back to the top left when I reopen the application.

Comment: What does "blocked" mean to you? To me, the window does not always appear in the same place. It depends on whether other windows are open or not.

Comment: Please add additional information by [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1467333/edit) the question, and don't add new answers

Comment: And no matter where I put the window on the screen, each time I restart an application from the snapstore, it returns to its default location!

Comment: Sorry, I'm on my way to instinct, being a unilingual French-speaking Quebecer and I work by google translation, so sorry for the inaccuracies in the translation that this may cause!

Comment: The site is in English so I don't understand everything :)

Comment: Je ne savais même pas ce que ça voulais dire add comment , maintenant je le sais :)

Comment: But back to my original question. Is it normal that the snapstore application windows return to their default location each time the application is opened?

Comment: And no, I'm not an alien , I'm just a French speaker who lives in North America and who has to deal with customer services that are mostly in English!

Even in a country where it's supposedly an official language :)

Comment: Can anyone answer my question?